# how to avoiding splitting string python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am reading data from file inputfile.txt:

inputfile.txt:

```
    sch,tab,"select no,name,place from test"
    sch1,tab1,"select no,name,place from test1"

file1 = open('inputfile.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()
[sch,tab,query]=line.split(",")
print(query)
```

It is printing like :`'select no'`

My expected output is : `'select no,name,place from test'`

how to print complete  query instead of sub query.

Comment: Unless you are specifically asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed the former.

Comment: If your actual question is how to avoid splitting quoted strings, probably look into the `csv` module, which does exactly this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `csv` module with `quotechar='"'`

**Ex:**

```
import csv

with open('inputfile.txt') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, quotechar='"')
    for line in reader:
        sch,tab,query =line
        print(query)
```

**Output:**

```
select no,name,place from test
select no,name,place from test1
```

Answer (score 1):

Split into 3 parts using second parameter to split()

```
[sch,tab,query]=line.split(",", 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you split by `,` it will consider it from query as well.

You can split by `select` and use the last string as query check below example:

```
query = 'select ' + line.split('select')[-1]
```

or if your pattern is fix then you can do like this:

```
query = ','.join(line.split(',')[2:])
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers are correct but from what I think you're trying to do, check out the shlex module on python.org: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html